# Generic `count` function

Tags: c++

In the C++ book, I have met next function:

```
template<class Container>
int count(const Container& container) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(auto&& elt : container) {
        sum += 1;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I am just wondering why we use here reference to reference `auto&&` instead of just reference `auto&` ?

Comment: It is known as **rvalue reference**.

Comment: There are no references to references

Comment: @ArdentCoder, ok. But what I lose if I will use **reference** in this example, instead of **rvalue reference** ?

Comment: @ArdentCoder Actually, it's a forwarding reference.

Comment: @demas Yes, that's your original question. My comment was just intended to let you know of the exact term for "reference to reference", which is not actually a reference to reference.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings There are many more terms like "universal reference" as well ;)

Comment: Indeed. But it may not be an rvalue reference.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I was just not being too specific: "forwarding reference is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter" :P

Comment: @ArdentCoder That's not a good description of a forwarding reference; it seems to be describing the symbols rather than the semantics, and doing so incorrectly. The `auto` part makes it different from any old `T&&` for some concrete `T`.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings You shall ask a separate question on terminology if you're not getting what I mean

Comment: @ArdentCoder I don't need to ask a question because I know what a forwarding reference is, and how it differs from an rvalue reference. :)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Of course there's a difference, and [I didn't deny that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61975831/generic-count-function#comment109614724_61975831).

Comment: @Ardent Presumably then you will be removing your initial comment wherein you claim there is an rvalue reference in the question. :)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings As you can see in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61975831/generic-count-function#comment109614675_61975831), my initial comment was intended to show "reference to reference" is not yet a feature of C++.

Comment: @ArdentCoder May as well say "it is known as **strawberry milkshake**" to make the same point.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I just felt that "rvalue reference" would give more of a starting point than "strawberry milkshake" to the OP. Moreover, I don't want the OP to go outside and buy milkshakes in this season.

Comment: @ArdentCoder It may be possible to get them on Amazon Prime :)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Oh no, more problems in that case: poor delivery boys would suffer as well, unless you've made virtual reality a reality.

Comment: Optimus Prime could kick Amazon Prime's butt.

Comment: @user4581301 Can't argue with that tbh